# NodeJS Q and module

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

I have two files, `layer-token.js` and `server.js`.

`layer-token` generates a JWT token, I am using promises using Q to go through the process step by step, everything work fine and the token is generated.

My problem is how to pass the token back to `server.js`, currently the value of `LayerSessionToken` comes out as `[Object Promise]`, how do I access the actual value?

**server.js**

```
LayerSessionToken = layerToken.generateToken();
```

**layertoken.js**

```
var returnSessionToken = function(Sessiontoken) {
return Sessiontoken;

}

module.exports = {
    generateToken : function()
    {
       LayerToken= getNonce()
       .then(getIdentityToken)
       .then(getSession)
       .then(returnSessionToken)
       .fail(function (error) {
            response.write('Computer says no, ' + error.message);
       });
     return LayerToken
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `layertoken.js` returns a Promise `LayerToken`. To get the actual value you call `.then` on it

```
LayerSessionToken = layerToken.generateToken();
LayerSessionToken.then(function(actualValue){
    // do something with actualValue
});
```

[More info on how Promises work](http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html)